# tensorflow manipulate labels vector into "multiple hot encoder"

Tags: tensorflow

is it possible (in a nice way, that is) in tensorflow to achieve the next functionality:

assume we have a dense vector of tags

```
labels = [0,3,1,2,0]
```

I need to make a "multiple hot encoder" of it. meaning, for each row I need 1's up to the index of the label minus 1
so the required result will be

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using tf.nn.embeddings_lookup as shown here:

```
embeddings = tf.constant([[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,1], [1,1,1]])
labels = [0,3,1,2,0]
encode_tensors = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings,labels)
```

Output of sess.run(encode_tensors) :

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

for completion:

it's also possible to use:

```
In [397]: labels = np.array([1, 2, 0, 3, 0])
In [398]: sess.run(tf.sequence_mask(labels, 3, dtype=tf.int8))
Out[398]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

the result matrix will be reversed from what I asked though